# Rails: Elegant way to find name from related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to models:
Father has_many Children
`f_name`

Child belongs_to Father

 `c_name
 father_id(fk)`

In children's index page I want to show c_name and fathers' name

```
<% @children.each do |child|%>
  <%= child.name %>
  <% if Father.find(child.father_id) %>
    <%= Father.find(child.father_id).f_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I do not think the code is elegant. Maybe I should put them into helper or model, but I do not know how to do that. 
Anybody help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your controller looks like, but it can be like this.

```
@children = Child.includes(:father)
```

in view:

```
<% @children.each do |child|%>
  <%= child.name %>
  <%= child.father.try(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

`try` does same as `<%= child.father.name if child.father %>`

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I want to put this in helper, but I found that in my project there is an folder called decorator where people puts some functions. Do you know why people use decorator folder?

Comment: Decorator is way to organize your helpers. Rails helpers are just methods that all available in view layer. Decorator way is allow create helpers that related to specific object. `child_father_name(child)` will became `child.father_name` after decoration.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you have your relationships correctly setup in your models then rails will give you some nice helper methods. In this case to find a child's father you can do: `child.father`. Then of course `child.father.name` to get the name of the father.

If you're worried that a child does not have a father then you could do something like:

```
<%= child.father.name if child.father %>
```